# PostgreSQL: Equivalent way to express the following Oracle SQL, HH.MI.SSXFF AM

Tags: postgresql, date, timestamp

The oracle script I'm in the process of 'converting' so it can be executed in PGAdmin4, has the following values to insert into a column of table with a data type of 'date'

```
to_timestamp('12-JUN-99','DD-MM-YY HH.MI.SSXFF AM')
```

From my understanding, FF represents Fractional Seconds.

What would be the equivalent way to represent the statement in PostgreSQL/PGAdmin 4?

SSXFF is my main concern.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how that code works in Oracle.  But this should work in both Postgres and Oracle:

```
select to_timestamp('12-JUN-99', 'DD-MON-YY')
```

Comment: Will this include the hour minute and second automatically?

Comment: will set time to `00:00:00` your string doesnt have any time information anyway

Comment: Thanks for the tip on MON instead of MM. The following statement 'insert into practice_01 values(1, to_timestamp('05-JAN-57','DD-MON-YY'));' inserted, 2057-01-05, instead of 1957-01-05.

Comment: @user1815210: use `RR` Instead of `YY` but you should **really** avoid ambiguous or language dependent formats. Use ANSI SQL literals instead.`date '2057-01-05'` or `timestamp '2057-01-05 14:15:16'`

Comment: If YY is just used, then the the century (e.g. 19YY or 20YY), who's YY is closer to 2020 is used.